# Compiler Provided Copy CTOR

Tags: c++

What is the memory allocated to `char *ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{ 
  private:
  int count;
  char *ptr;                                 
  public :
  void print()
  {    
  cout << "Addr " << &ptr << endl;     
  cout << "Addr " << *ptr << endl;     
  }       

};

int main()
{
 A obj;
 obj.print();
 A *obj1 = new A(obj); 
 obj1->print();
 cin.get();             
 return 0;   
}
```

I am using compiler provided copy constructor. I am interested in understanding how much memory will me allocated to the `*ptr`.

Comment: It is just the memory used by a `char*`, i.e. `sizeof(char*)` bytes.

Comment: The example you provided will not compile because the `ptr` is never initialized so the line `cout << "Addr " << *ptr << endl;` will segfault

Comment: @MattClarkson wrong on both counts - it will compile but will produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore sorry, I was wrong, it _will_ compile and I guess will dereference an uninitialized pointer, so yes, it could print *anything* or segfault.  UB is always fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How much memory? Well, none at all**. All you have is an unitialised `char*`, itself occupying `sizeof(char*)` bytes of memory. You will need to  allocate memory yourself (perhaps with a `new`) and assign that memory to `ptr`. Don't forget to free the memory (perhaps with a `delete`) once you're done with it; typically done in a destructor.

Better still, use `std::string` which takes care of all the memory for you.

(P.S. technically the line `cout << "Addr " << *ptr << endl;` gives you *undefined behaviour* as you are dereferencing an unitialised pointer).

Comment: `obj1` is not stack allocated. So neither is it's `ptr` member.

Comment: @Juanchopanza: good point. Have removed: outside the answer scope to point out the difference between obj and obj1.

Answer (score 1):

The `char *` alone will take up 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine, 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine. When you assign a memory (allocated using `new` perhaps) to `ptr` only the address of the memory is stored in `ptr` and the actual memory is allocated on the heap.